# load class file from classpath

Tags: java, classpath

I want to load class files from module dependencies (external jar files in the classpath). When I tried getResourceAsStream I got null pointer exception:

```
ClassParser parser = new ClassParser(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/net/FTP.class"), "FTP.class");

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.classfile.ClassParser.<init>(ClassParser.java:101)
    at ParaNamesTest.printUtilsParNames(ParaNamesTest.java:52)
    at ParaNamesTest.main(ParaNamesTest.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

ant.jar on myclasspath but still java can't find it what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask the class loader of your class (`this.getClass()`) for a resource from a different JAR, this won't work.

Try replacing `... (this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(...` by `... (FTP.class.getResourceAsStream(...` whith `FTP` being imported as `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.net.FTP`.

If you have the class name only at runtime, you can dynamically get a `Class` object by using the fully qualified class name and `Class.forName`:

```
String className = "org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.net.FTP";
... (Class.forName(className).getResourceAsStream( ...
```

Comment: is there another way to load classes as the class name would be given at runtime

Comment: Yes, using `Class.forName()`. I updated my answer to include sample code for that way as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you getting null for this resource it means this class could not be found in your class path.  I would try @Philipp's suggestion (not because its more likely to work) but because it will make it obvious if this class is on your class path.

Answer (score 0):

use `Class.forName("java.lang.String")` for example to get `String.class`