# How to get the file path

Tags: java

I have test.json file inside my package (com.test.new) of Project .

```
File file = new File("test.json");
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
             JSONObject data = (JSONObject) parser.parse(
                      new FileReader(file.getPath()));//path to the JSON file.
               System.out.println(data.toString());
```

Getting Exception :-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.json (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
```

How to get the file path location?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [load class file from classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305195/load-class-file-from-classpath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can depends how you build and run your application: do you create a jar file, or not?

Can you check in your bin (or equivalent) sub-directory, after building, where is located the json file?
It should be something like com/test/new/test.json from 'current directory'.

This way, you then could easily get the Absolute path of your file this way:

```
File file = new File("com/test/new/test.json");
String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

You can get all Documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath--).

But, it would be safer to add a safe-guard, ensuring first the file exists:

```
File file = new File("com/test/new/test.json");
if (!file.exists()) {
    // Implement safe-guard ... for instance logging error or throwing an exception
}
```

Comment: I tried getAbsolutePath() but getting same exception

Comment: I completed my answer.